# ManyToOne Join Column with static value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I´ve got a table with different id->text values. These are distinguished by a third column. So only the combination of the id and the third column are unique and should result in the text-value.

In SQL I know how to solve this. It would be something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM objekp AS o 
JOIN txtpop AS t ON o.bulakz = t.txtwert 
WHERE t.txtart = 'BULAKZ'
```

'BULAKZ' is the static value from the third column because there is more than one *txtwert* with value 1 for example in the *txtpop* table.

I´ve tried it with multiple @JoinColumn but i was not able to add the static value. @WhereJoinTable did also not work. Maybe I used the wrong values.

Can anyone help me to find a solution to solve this problem with JPA and hibernate? Thanks in advance

Comment: It is totally a JPA hibernate question. I know an SQL solution but need a solution for JPA hibernate.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I read it wrong the first time around.